# JQuery Autocomplete clears textbox of previous data?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a jquery autocomplete on a text field and I am using a hacky way to allow autocomplete multiple times in the same text box. Basically you can comma separate a value and then a regex matcher will try to match on the term only after the final value. For example I can have dog,cat,pi in the text box and the jquery will autocomplete for pig because I only pass "pi" to the autocomplete. The only issue with my approach is that if a user clicks on the autocomplete offer then all previous data(dog,cat) disappears and is replaced by the autocomplete value "pig". Any ideas on how to be able to click on the suggestions without erasing previous data?

```
   function filterResults(myList, matcher) {
                    var retGrep = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
                        if (matcher.test(myList[i])) {
                            retGrep.push(myList[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    return retGrep;
                }
                $("#title").autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        if(request.term.indexOf(',') != -1){
                            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term.substr(request.term.lastIndexOf(',') + 1));
                        }else{
                            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
                        }
                            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
                            var results = filterResults(titleList, matcher);
                            response(results.slice(0, 5));

                    },
                    messages: {
                        noResults: '',
                        results: function() {}
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: I posted it... no comments.. come on....

Comment: we actually don't get alerted to the edit change so its easy to miss. Thats why you want to make sure all the info is in the question from the start so you can get the best of our help.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a fix for you without having to mod the actual plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/w4p6s002/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var buffer ="";
    function filterResults(myList, matcher) {
                    var retGrep = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
                        if (matcher.test(myList[i])) {
                            retGrep.push(myList[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    return retGrep;
                }
                $("#title").autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        if(request.term.indexOf(',') != -1){
                            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term.substr(request.term.lastIndexOf(',') + 1));
                        }else{
                            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
                        }
                            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
                            var results = filterResults(["taco","pig","help"], matcher);
                            response(results.slice(0, 5));

                    },
                    messages: {
                        noResults: '',
                        results: function() {

                        }
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        buffer = $("#title").val().substring(0,$("#title").val().lastIndexOf(",")+1);
                    }, 
                    close: function( event, ui ) {
                        $(this).val(buffer + $("#title").val());
                    }
                });


});
```

I added the 2 event listeners in your code so when a selection occurs it saves the string in a buffer before it is changed. Then when it is changed it prepends that text before the autocompleted value.

Comment: Sidenote: this won't work if you use a different delimiter longer than one character... you'll have to modify the select function a little bit.

Comment: I mean the close function.

Comment: Well yea but your example was just a comma. It would be a simple change if the delimiter was anything else.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't saying yours was wrong, but if someone happened to copy paste this code i was giving them a heads up/